# Pressing the hyphen key twice doesn't get me two hyphens

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Whenever I'm typing and I need two dashes (like when using git log --pretty) pressing the dash key twice doesn't work. It only shows one, then I need to go back and type another one.

When typing multiple dashes I noticed a delay as if the dash is a start of a shortcut or a command, but I looked over all the shortcut settings, iBus settings, compose keys settings and didn't find anything.

Does anyone know the reason for this behavior?

Edit: I am using a laptop with an usb keyboard, the problem doesn't happen when using the laptop's keyboard.

Comment: Is your external keyboard set to use a different keyboard layout than the laptop's regular keyboard?

Comment: Does this happen in all applications? Does it also happen in a tty?

Comment: Yes, both keyboards use the same method and it happens in all applications including tty

Comment: This is apparently an issue with my keyboard. It stopped happening after I got a new one.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be an accessibility feature.

Open the *Settings* app, and find in the sidebar, near the bottom, the *Universal Access* item.

Look through what is enabled.

A good candidate for this feature is *Typing Assist*. When clicked, it opens a dialog, in which you will find *Bounce keys*. By the description, it might be the one that impacts your experience.

Comment: Typing assist is off. The only thing I have on is Cursor blinking. Thanks for the idea though.